# Are height & width measured the same on all monitors?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Is Width = 103; the same on all monitors ?

Comment: I have no idea what the world you are asking here.

Comment: I only know, that WPF uses unit-independent units. But I would too like to know if UI rendering takes into account display or system DPI. But I would guess no.

Comment: I am asking if i make a program and run it on some other computer if width for axample of 103 is the same or is it dependable on the pixels of a monitor. Really a simple question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It represents the pixels. So if you do have a higher resolution, it is smaller. Even on the same monitor.

Comment: I am working a lot on fixed width and i want to know if the program won't be messed up on some older monitor by my boss computer. So that 103 won't be 104 or something like that.

Comment: if you have a total width on the monitor from 800px and your width is set to 103 then this are 103. when the monitor is set to 480px total width then your width is also 103.

Answer (score 3):

No.  It's a width in pixels that are sort-of device independent, but pretty obviously such device independence doesn't magically apply if you mirror your laptop's screen onto a video projector showing a 60ft wide picture.

You will not find a way to put things onto monitors at an exact physical size, without getting the user to run some kind of calibration process for their specific setup.

Comment: Well. Display can report its dimensions, resolution and size of pixels (not sure if it is doing it tho), so there is no need to magicaly measure something. But I think WPF UI rendering is not clever enough to make use of this.

Comment: Euphoric, so when your PC is showing the same image on two monitors of different resolution (see my example), which should it use?  And if you set it to use just the video projector, would you *really* want everything rescaled?  In many situations, what you really care about is the angular size of a pixel at the eyeball of the viewer, which the monitor can't hep you with.

Answer (score 1):

WPF units are based on 96DPI (dots/pixels per inch) so 103 means 1.072" or 2.72cm

This value is then multiplied with the monitors DPI to find out how many pixels it should be.

If the monitor is 96 DPI it will be 103 pixels but if the monitor is 150 DPI it will be 160 pixels.

**This is the theory but in practice it doesn't work.**

1. DPI is a user setting and not a monitor setting (at least in windows)! i.e. a user will have the same DPI setting regardless of monitor used. My laptop is 150 DPI and my desk monitors are around 100 DPI. I keep DPI set to around 110 since changing DPI requires logoff.
2. The DPI dialog in windows is sort of backwards since it talks about text size. (In my opinion you increase textsize with a larger font not by fooling the system about your monitor size and resolution.) The effect is that users set the DPI based on the text size they want not the monitor's physical properties.

---

If you want to calibrate your DPI settings you can use the "Custom DPI setting".[image: Custom DPI Setting]
The idea is that you hold a ruler against the monitor and drags the on-screen ruler until they match in size.

Having a correct DPI setting will give you images and text with the same size on the monitor aa on paper.